# Newborn photography - Lens for crop Nikon D7200

Tags: lens, nikon

I want to start photograph newborns. But know I am pretty comfused which lens would be good on my Nikon D7200 crop camera.? Everywhere i look for information all suggestions are for full frame camera.
At start I wanted 24-70mm lens, bur now I dont know. 
So maybe you can help me decide. Which lens could give me sharp pictures and beautiful bokeh?

:)

Comment: I would look at the sigma art 50 1.4, or if that is to narrow their 35.

Comment: Thank you a lot for answers. :) yeah, that bokeh effect I more wanted later for sitter sesions or cake smash. :) And how do you think would 24-70mm would be sharp enough.?

Comment: $125 used Nikkor 35mm f/1.8G DX is all you really need for baby.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What gear do I need for a newborn photography session?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/77817/what-gear-do-i-need-for-a-newborn-photography-session)

Comment: @lijat please don't post answers in comments. Please write an answer if you're going to answer the question. Ref: [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/please-put-your-answers-in-the-answers-section-even-if-theyre-short)

Comment: @chulster please don't post answers in comments. Please write an answer if you're going to answer the question. Ref: [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/please-put-your-answers-in-the-answers-section-even-if-theyre-short)

Comment: @lijat When properly focused the Sigma 50mm f/1.4 ART is certainly a sharp lens, but its bokeh is not the smoothest in the world. There are lots of other lenses with more pleasing out of focus highlights.

Answer (score 2):

I have D7200, I am shooting with Sigma 18-35mm f/1.8 DC HSM Art. The pictures which are coming from this lens are superb. Super sharp even wide open, it really took me by surprise how good it is. At 35mm you have equivalent of 50mm FF. It is a bit heavy lens, around 810 g. A bit more expensive, but the build/image quality is totaly worth it.

Another one would be Tamron SP 17-50mm f/2,8 XR Di II VC. It is much cheaper, build quality is a bit less. Not as sharp wide open, but you have more range. At f8 it is as sharp as the Sigma.

I am sure if you look these up, you will find a lot of sample pictures and reviews.

If you need more range. Than the Sigma 50-100mm f/1,8 Art is super sharp. Same series as 18-35, a bit more expensive and the range is not the biggest. But for portraits it is all you need.

It mainly depens on you budget, but I have to say, Sigma 18-35 is just perfect for me. Bokeh would be better on some primes of APS-C 50mm+. But even the sigma at 35mm can do some nice bokeh shots, I am sure you can find some on flick Sigma 18-35 group.

Here is a shot (nothing great, just some plant shot at f1.8. iso 280), as you can see it is sharp wide open and even some small bokeh.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/KvNgVdZiwyrXaprw5

Answer (score 1):

> I want to start photograph newborns... Which lens could give me sharp pictures and beautiful bokeh?

**None.** For newborns, you usually won't get good bokeh no matter what lens you use because they are usually lying directly on the "background". They can't crawl or sit up or even raise their head. You can try different compositions with parent + baby, but then you'd need deeper depth of field to get both in focus.

> Everywhere i look for information all suggestions are for full frame camera. At start I wanted 24-70mm lens, bur now I dont know.

24-70/2.8 is fine on crop sensor. You just don't get the 18-24 range that most kit lenses afford. For your purpose, it doesn't matter that much because people usually don't look good at wide focal lengths.

> ... would 24-70mm... be sharp enough.?

I'd expect a Nikkor lens to be plenty sharp because Nikon generally competes with Canon and the EF 24-70/2.8 L IS II USM is very sharp. If you can get a good price on a used model, you should be able to resell it to spend less than a rental fee if you decide you don't like it.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. +1 for posting a good and expanded answer. =)